# How to delete value from JSON file with HTTP request and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

Assume a JSON file on a server contains ['one','two','three'].

If an HTML button click event occurs and a variable is set to 'two',
How do you use HTTP request and PHP to delete 'two' from the JSON file if the num variable value matches 'two' in the JSON file?

**UPDATE!!!** Same value returns after button click

**Files (JS & HTML):**

```js
$('#button1').click(function() {
  let num = 'two';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./update.php",
    data: num
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Button Writer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button1" type="button">Write to File</button>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JSON File:** (***codes.json***)

```
["one","two","three"]
```

**PHP File** (***update.php***)

```
<?php
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('./codes.json');//Read here the json file into text
$array = json_decode($jsonContents);

$value = $_POST;

if (($key = array_search($value, $array )) !== false) {
   unset($array [$key]);
}

$jsonString = json_encode($array);
//Here you can save the content of $jsonString into the file again
file_put_contents("./codes.json", $jsonString);

echo $jsonString;
?>
```

Comment: "if this value matches 2" ...what value are you talking about? and what do you want to do with the new altered JSON? put it back in the file?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. what I  mean is to send an HTTP request the value of the variable num to splice out 'two' from the JSON file if there is a match.

Comment: the value of what variable?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Take a look at the JS file. let num = 'two'; on button click event

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: Mind that your JSON file is invalid: JSON only works with double (") quotes.

Comment: You are not sending num to PHP: Within $.ajax [ data: "" ] should be [ data: num ]

Answer (score 1):

Then on the server, you can:

```
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'); //Read here the json file into text
$array = json_decode($jsonContents);

$value = $_POST["num"];

if (($key = array_search($value, $array )) !== false) {
   unset($array[$key]);
}

$jsonString = json_encode($array);
//Here you can save the content of $jsonString into the file again
file_put_contents('path/to/file.json', $jsonString);
```

Comment: +1 if you change the first line to `$jsonContents = file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'); // comment...` so PHP doesn't throw a syntax error

Comment: @Tyblitz I changed the first line and  tried to write to file `file_put_contents("./codes.json", $jsonString);` but values in the JSON file still returns the same. Check the contents of my PHP code above to see if I did something wrong

Comment: @claOnline The code is valid, except you should remove the space between `$array [$key]`. If it's not that, you probably have a server permission issue (check [PHP function chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)), try doing `chmod('./code.json', 0755)` before you `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @Tyblitz. Did everything removed space and added chmod function. It still does not work. Still returns

`["one","two","three"]`
instead of

`["one","three"]`  Anyway, I am testing with XAMPP on windows 10 pc.

Comment: @claOnline Check all other possible points of failure. Does your AJAX call succeed, does PHP respond, etc.? In any case, this falls outside the scope of your original question, and you should probably signal to the community that this answer is correct by accepting it as it does answer the question in the title.